# Glob understanding

Tags: java, glob

I need to develop a file scanner in java with the following options / parameters:

1. One directory
2. One or more pattern like *.xml, *.txt, *test.csv
3. Switch for recursive scanning

I think the best way would be something like this:

```
public class FileScanningTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String directory = "C:\\tmp\\scanning\\";
        String glob      = "**/*.xml";
        Boolean rekursiv = false;

        final PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:"+glob);

        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(directory), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
                    System.out.println(path);
                } 
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I do not understand why I have to put "**/" in front of my actual pattern. Also this does make the scanning recursive. If I remove **/, the application is not finding anything anymore.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob tells that ** means recursive, but why this is not working if I remove that?

Can somebody give me a hint?

Thanks everyone and have a nice weekend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To recursively find `*.xml` using a glob starting from the directory `/tmp/scanning/` please have a look at this sample. It works with Linux Ubuntu and does what you want. It works like the Unix find utility. I didn't test it on other OS than Ubuntu, but you should only need to change the filename separator.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;

import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitOption.*;

import java.util.*;


public class FileScanningTest {

    public static class Finder
            extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

        private final PathMatcher matcher;
        private int numMatches = 0;

        Finder(String pattern) {
            matcher = FileSystems.getDefault()
                    .getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
        }

        // Compares the glob pattern against
        // the file or directory name.
        void find(Path file) {
            Path name = file.getFileName();
            if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)) {
                numMatches++;
                System.out.println(file);
            }
        }

        // Prints the total number of
        // matches to standard out.
        void done() {
            System.out.println("Matched: "
                    + numMatches);
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each file.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                                         BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            find(file);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each directory.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                                                 BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            find(dir);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file,
                                               IOException exc) {
            System.err.println(exc);
            return CONTINUE;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException {
        boolean recursive = false;
        Path startingDir = Paths.get("/tmp/scanning");
        String pattern = "*.{html,xml}";

        Finder finder = new Finder(pattern);
        if (!recursive) {
            Path dir = startingDir;
            List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
            try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.{xml,html}")) {
                for (Path entry : stream) {
                    files.add(entry.toFile());
                }

                for (File xmlfile : files) {
                    System.out.println(xmlfile);
                }
            } catch (IOException x) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("error reading folder %s: %s",
                        dir,
                        x.getMessage()),
                        x);
            }
        } else {    
            Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, finder);
            finder.done();
        }

    }
}
```

Test

```
 ~> java FileScanningTest
/tmp/scanning/dir2/test2.xml
/tmp/scanning/blah.xml
Matched: 2
```

If you want to match either `*.xml` or `test3.html`, then you can use this pattern: `String pattern = "{*.xml,test3.html}";`

Comment: Thanks. That works also on windows platforms.

But how can I disable the recursive scanning? We do have an option to disable recursive scanning. And is there a way to have several different patterns at the same time?

Comment: @Hauke Yes. To disable recursive scanning, all you need is an option from the user e.g. `args[0]` and you can use several different patterns with a regular expression. I can show you or you can ask a new question. I can update the code I posted according to your specification. I also like learning how this is done in Java (I do it a lot in C.)

Comment: If you could update your code that would be great. This is just a testing class it would be okay with a boolean flag "recursive" instead of analysing the application arguments. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Hauke This works for several filetypes: `String pattern = "*.{html,xml}";`

Comment: @Hauke Now please try the code again. It has two branches, one for recursing and one for non-recursive. And a `boolean` for choosing whether to recurse. And finds both html and xml now.

Comment: Great is working. How could I do a pattern like "*.xml" and "test*.html"?

Comment: One way to do it is to implement the `or` word so that you can search for `*.xml` or `test.html` similar to the Unix utilify `find -o`. I didn't try it, but it could work to use `|` for logical `OR` like this `String pattern = "*.xml|test.html";`or similar. A regex can do it, with a little more work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122579/discussion-between-hauke-and-dac-saunders).

Comment: +1 for the last line since I could not find why my comma-seperated-globs does not work (did not know the curly braces!)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `*` and `**` is that `*` will never match a directory separator (`/` or `\` depending on your OS), but `**` will.  Given a file tree like this:

```
a/
  b.xml
c/
  a.xml
da.xml
```

The pattern `*a.xml` will only match `da.xml` (not `c/a.xml` since that contains a `/`), while the pattern `**a.xml` will match both `da.xml` and `c/a.xml`, and the pattern `a**.xml` will only match `a/b.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. That means I could only use the pattern *a.xml if I am located already in the directory without giving the whole path?